# Optimization of modular exponentiation using fft

Tags: algorithms, optimization, modular-arithmetic, fast-fourier-transform

My math prof said it is trivial to optimize a modular exponentiation (a^b mod c) problem for large values using fft, but I can't figure out how to do this. I looked it up and found a few papers on it (namely [[1]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8307235), [[2]](http://www.globalcis.org/jcit/ppl/50_%20JCIT_JUNE_Binder1-50.pdf), and [[3]](http://users.wpi.edu/~xhuang/pubs/2015_huang_tcas2.pdf)), but 2 of them use Montgomery multiplication, although in different ways, and the third one uses a completely different algorithm to the best of my understanding. I didn't fully understand the papers and can't find anything else on this subject outside these 3 papers. How would one do this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Fourier_transform_methods

Comment: @D.W. How does one implement that into a modular exponentiation algorithm? My understanding is an improvement into solely the multiplication aspect is minimally helpful.

Comment: My understanding is opposite to yours.

Comment: Corresponding posts on [math.se]: [Optimization of modular exponentiation using fft](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3559697) and on [mathoverflow.se]: [Optimization of modular exponentiation using fft](https://mathoverflow.net/q/353496).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Ah I see. So this would then be implemented as a subroutine to something such as the LR Binary algorithm for modular exponentiation, allowing the multiplication part to be significantly sped up?

Comment: Right, that’s my understanding.