# Optimization of modular exponentiation using fft

Tags: optimization, algorithms, modular-arithmetic, fast-fourier-transform

My math/cs professor said it is trivial to optimize a modular exponentiation ($a^b \bmod c$) problem using fft, yet I am not able to understand how to do this.

I found 3 papers on this ([[1]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8307235), [[2]](http://www.globalcis.org/jcit/ppl/50_%20JCIT_JUNE_Binder1-50.pdf), and [[3]](http://users.wpi.edu/~xhuang/pubs/2015_huang_tcas2.pdf)). Papers 1 and 3 use Montgomery reduction, that too in different ways, and paper 2 seems to use a unique method compared to the other 2. I was not able to fully understand the papers not find any other material on this subject.

How would you optimize modular exponentiation using fft?

Comment: Ask your professor for help in understanding since it is so trivial.

Comment: What is a? An integer, complex number, a polynomial or something else?

Comment: @narekBojikian an integer (it's modular exponentiation)

Comment: @Somos Unfortunately my prof isn't the most helpful in situations such as these. He gave a spiel at the start of the semester than if we came to him with easy questions he would just recommend we drop the class, because we "need to learn how to google and not always rely on the prof".

Comment: He might have meant binary method check this here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optimization of modular exponentiation using fft](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/121109/optimization-of-modular-exponentiation-using-fft)

Comment: @narekBojikian how does that relate to fft?

Comment: It does not that is why I wrote it im a comment. I thought there might have been some sort of misunderstanding